# Counting game discord js

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js, counting

Hewo everyone. I created my own bot
 I have a lot of great things like games etc.
However, I want to do a couting game.
I have a channel called "Counting"
And i want to setup my bot do like:

User 1: 456

User 2: 457

**Bot**: 458

My question is, How can I make the bot count when no one else is counting? But just once. (Look the example^^)

If you can, can you give me an example code please? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const {Client} = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client()

// Stores the current count.
let count = 0
// Stores the timeout used to make the bot count if nobody else counts for a set period of
// time.
let timeout

// Discord.js v12:
// client.on('message', ({channel, content, member}) => {
// Discord.js v13:
client.on('messageCreate', ({channel, content, member}) => {
  // Only do this for the counting channel of course
  // If you want to simply make this work for all channels called 'counting', you
  // could use this line:
  // if (client.channels.cache.filter(c => c.name === 'counting').has(channel.id))
  if (channel.id === 'counting channel id') {
    // You can ignore all bot messages like this
    if (member.user.bot) return
    // If the message is the current count + 1...
    if (Number(content) === count + 1) {
      // ...increase the count
      count++
      // Remove any existing timeout to count
      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)
      // Add a new timeout
      timeout = setTimeout(
        // This will make the bot count and log all errors
        () => channel.send(++count).catch(console.error),
        // after 30 seconds
        30000
      )
    // If the message wasn't sent by the bot...
    } else if (member.id !== client.user.id) {
      // ...send a message because the person stuffed up the counting (and log all errors)
      channel.send(`${member} messed up!`).catch(console.error)
      // Reset the count
      count = 0
      // Reset any existing timeout because the bot has counted so it doesn't need to
      // count again
      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
  }
})

client.login('your token')
```

---

## Explanation

When a user (that isn't the bot) sends a message in the counting channel, the bot checks if the user is counting correctly (`if (Number(content) === count + 1`)).
If they are, it increments `count`, removes the timeout if it exists (`if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)`), and schedules the bot to count after 30 seconds (`setTimeout(() => channel.send(++count), 30000)`).
If they aren't, the bot sends a message, resets `count`, and clears the timeout (if it exists).

When the bot sends a message, it won't trigger any of that. When the bot counts, `Number(content) === count` because it was already incremented.

Comment: So ,it work aswell, the problem is: 
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/684800423252852746/705744991435227196/unknown.png.

Also, I need to know how the bot deletes message when it detects messages who aren't number.

Comment: Also, how can I ignore messages from bots, like Pokecord, who send message in the counting and so, the counting bot restart to 0. 
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/685513573392318475/705755696595075162/unknown.png

Comment: Use `if (member.author.bot) return`. I edited that in in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! :D You help me a lot, thanks for help me! Continue like that :P